# Laravel - format date from Mysql database with carbon

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

In my Laravel project I have a MySQL database table with the following column:

```
 |   requested_at  |
 2018-02-03 12:00:00
 2018-03-03 11:00:00
```

I want to get all items from this column where the timestamp (requested_at) is older than 60 days:

```
$now = Carbon::now ();  

$60days  = DB::table('exampletable')->where('requested_at', '=', $now->subDays(60))->get();
```

For my following code I need to format the Date format from my column `requested at`.

I only want to get the date like this `2018-03-03` without the time.

I play around with some carbon methods but It didn't work at all:

```
$format60 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $60days);
```

Comment: FYI your variable `$60days` is invalid, variables **must** start with an underscore **OR** a letter.  As for the Carbon part it should look something like this, `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $days60['FIELD THAT HAS YOUR TIME VALUE']);` - note I changed your variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using TIMESTAMP type so

```
->where('requested_at', '<=', now()->subDays(60)->startOfDay())->get();
```

As you can see there is no need to format `Carbon` instance.

Break it all down:

```
now() // Laravel helper to get Carbon::now()
->subDays(60) // subtract 60 days
->startOfDay() // set time part of timestamp to start of the day
```

> **Note**: add `requested_at` into `$dates` [array in your model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) for easier use

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by mysql only, no need of carbon.
Just using **`datediff()`** and **`now()`** of mysql.
Do like this

```
$days60  = DB::table('exampletable')
    ->whereRaw('datediff(now(),requested_at) = 60')
    ->get();
```

Example :- [image]